# How to get more ad clicks on android apps or websites?

Tags: admob, ads, adsense

I'm designing a website and I'm adding ads to it. However, I want every user to click on multiple ads in my website to gain more from it. But from what I read, more than 2 clicks will not count.

So My question is, if more than 2 clicks on an ad will not count anymore, why do I see many android apps and games that make you watch a video ad every time you die in the game for example. Isn't watching the video ad once will make the user IP registered and hence any more video ads will not count?

So what is the reasoning behind those games developers making the user watching more than one video when the ads won't count anymore?

Answer (score 0):

I'm new to the advertising field, but I assume:

1. The ads vary, a user might be interested in third ad for example. And this may increase the CPM rate if the ads are CPM-based.
2. Advertise use tons of ads to increase the chances of clicking/Make
   you purchase a premium app version.